# SQL Azure database

Tags: sql, database, api, azure-sql-database, delete-file

Setting up SQL database API to create read update and delete Data in Azure

Comment: you haven't asked any question

Comment: Hi @Javeria, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such as SQL database API. We usually use REST API to manage the Azure SQL database.

You can create and manage servers and single databases in Azure SQL Database using the Azure portal, PowerShell, the Azure CLI, REST API, and Transact-SQL.

Choose the best one which is suitable for you.

Ref this document: [Create and manage servers and single databases in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-manage#rest-api)